# Is it possible to pipe a Bun ReadableStream to a Node JS stream?

Tags: bun

I want to pipe a Bun ReadableStream into a Node stream to process a CSV.

Is there a way to convert a Bun ReadableStream to a Node.js compatible one?

The docs for PapaParse shows this example:

https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/README.md#papa-parse-for-node
https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/tests/node-tests.js#L137

```js
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/long-sample.csv', 'utf8');
var csvStream = readStream.pipe(Papa.parse(Papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT));
csvStream.on('data', function(item) {
    data.push(item);
});
```

Comment: Why not use `fs.createReadStream("/long-sample.csv");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Recently i have the same problem. I used Transform stream(Combination between Writable and Readble). readable can

```js
import { Transform } from "stream";
const stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array> = file.stream()

const nodeStream = new Transform()

stream.pipeTo(new WritableStream({
    write(value){   
      nodeStream.push(value)
    },
    close(){
      nodeStream.push(null)
    }
 }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Bun ReadableStreams seem to be working imperfectly at the moment, due to https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/pull/6720. However, Bun does have some other interesting built-in ways to deal with file input; in your case, it looks like you might be able to utilize BunFile's [text](https://bun.sh/docs/api/file-io#reading-files-bun-file) option.

```js
let bunFile = Bun.file("/long-sample.csv");
let data = await bunFile.text();
let parsed = Papa.parse(data, config);
```

To the best of my knowledge, I believe that the Bun's ReadableStream should function as a drop-in replacement for Node's ReadableStream once it is repaired.